# equivalence class of kernel relation of floor function

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

[image]

By taking particular values of $k$, I found that equivalence class of $k$, $[k]=\{k,k+1,k+2,...,2k-1\}$, equivalence class of $2k$, $[2k]=\{2k,2k+1,2k+2,...,3k-1\}$ and so on, but how to present it properly.

Comment: $k \to \lfloor x/k \rfloor$ is a decreasing function. this means that $\lfloor x/k_1 \rfloor = \lfloor x/k_2 \rfloor$ iff there exists $n$ such that $\lfloor x/ n \rfloor \ge k_1 > \lfloor x/ (n+1) \rfloor$ and $\lfloor x/ n \rfloor \ge k_2 > \lfloor x/ (n+1) \rfloor$

Comment: note that the representative of some equivalence class is the smallest one, i.e. the $k$ such that $k = \lfloor x / \lfloor x / k \rfloor \rfloor$  (write $x = a k + b$ with $b < k$). and what is the book/course where you read that please ?

Comment: I asked you : where did you get that from ? thank you

Comment: One brother asked me this question, he got this in his assignment.